# How can I group by a time interval inside a specific period?

Tags: mysql, sql, period

Given the following structure and data:

```
user   initial_date           final_date 
'JOHN' '2016-05-05 18:21:51', '2016-05-05 18:50:34'
'JOHN' '2016-05-05 18:51:44', '2016-05-05 19:10:54'
```

And considering the period between `2016-05-05 00:00:00` and `2016-05-05 18:59:59`, I need to find out how much minutes John spent in these registers like this:

```
user   initial_date           final_date             minutes_spent
'JOHN' '2016-05-05 18:20:00', '2016-05-05 18:50:00'  30
'JOHN' '2016-05-05 18:51:00', '2016-05-05 19:10:00'  9
```

At the second line the result is 9 because my searching period is until 18:59:59, so must ignore the period after 19:00:00.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work for you:

```
select timestampdiff(MINUTE, greatest(initial_date,$start_of_range),
 least(final_date,$end_of_range)) from tbl where initial_date between 
 $start_of_range and $end_of_range or 
 final_date between $start_of_range and $end_of_range
```

?

Comment: Does this need an `OR final_date between $start_of_range and $end_of_range`?

Comment: @Uueerdo, you are right! So, the records that started after 18:00:00 but finished after will be summed too.

Comment: @dellasavia oh, wait, I've dealt with this kind of problem before; even now we are omitting intervals that start before the range and end after it.

Comment: I _think_ this is the smallest conditions that work `initial <= end AND final >= start`